# Efficiently Paginate Query when using multiple tables Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model in Django that gets its data from multiple tables.  The tables are partitioned externally by another program, which I have no control over.

To combat this and be able to query the data, I have a `get_model()` method to fetch the model class, and iterate over all the partitions then make a list

```py
class TagDataBase(BaseModel):
    tagid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    intvalue = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    floatvalue = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    stringvalue = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    datevalue = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    dataintegrity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    t_stamp = TimestampField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        abstract = True

def get_tagdata_model(name=None):

    class TagData(TagDataBase):
        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = name
            unique_together = (('tagid', 't_stamp'),)
            verbose_name = 'Tag Data'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Tag Data'
    return TagData
```

Then, to actually get the data, whenever I do a query, I do something like this

```py
data = []
for p in get_all_partitions():
    tags = get_tagdata_model(name=p.pname).objects.filter(tagid=tag.id)
    data.extend(tags)
```

We have pagination enabled on this view.  So it returns max 100 results at a time.

However, it seems to query/evaluate all possible data every time.  Whereas if I had one giant queryset, it would be sliced by the pagination and evaluate only the slice.

But I can't concat the querysets because they're technically different models.

Is there a way to either:

- Combine multiple querysets with "different" models or
- Create the django model in a way that allows it to span multiple partitions with formulaic names?